# ssh connection refused for root from remote host

Tags: centos, ssh

I have one host which I am struggling to allow remote access to - each time I try and connect I get connection refused.

On the target, I have checked the port is open:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2222                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      47081/sshd
```

and in sshd_config I have setup both allowed users and match permitrootlogin:

```
AllowUsers root@1.2.3.4

PermitRootLogin no

Match Address 1.2.3.4
        PermitRootLogin yes
```

When I try to connect from 1.2.3.4 I get connection refused using:

```
ssh -vv root@5.6.7.8 -p 2222
```

Response:

```
# ssh -vv root@5.6.7.8 -p 2222
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 5.6.7.8 [5.6.7.8] port 2222.
debug1: connect to address 5.6.7.8 port 2222: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host 5.6.7.8 port 2222: Connection refused
```

There is nothing in /var/log/secure or /var/log/messages on 5.6.7.8 to indicate a reason why it is being refused

SELinux is disabled and CSF is disabled with no other firewalls in between.

I can connect from my desktop to 5.6.7.8:2222 without any issues but not from another host (I have tried 2 different remote hosts) - what am I missing?

Comment: Is the real IP for 5.6.7.8 an RFC1918 address?

Comment: Are you actually getting a "Connection Refused" message or is it something else. Connection refused generally means nothing is listening on the target system or a firewall is blocking. Is there any port forwarding ? Are you sure that the 'target stem' is the same one that you are connecting to ? FWIW I can configure a system to work as you expect.

Comment: The real IP is not RFC1918 - it is public address

Comment: Yes I am getting connection refused - will update to show the output with verbose enabled

Answer (score 1):

Run tcpdump or tshark on the server and try to connect  from 1.2.3.4.

- Do you see a SYN from 1.2.3.4 followed by an ICMP packet back to 1.2.3.4? Then the problem is on the server.
- Do you see no SYN in the capture? Then something in the path is blocking the SYN, or something on 1.2.3.4.

Answer (score 0):

Try to connect with verbosity from both desktop and other host with issues and see what are differences in output:

```
ssh -vvv root@5.6.7.8 -p 2222
```

If that doesn't show you enough information, start sshd service on server with

```
$(which sshd) -d -p 2222
```

That will provide even more output. If that doesn't give you clear answer, check ssh versions on both hosts, there might been version incompatibilty if they differ.